# Neo4J online backup error on AWS - Failed to run a backup using the available strategies

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, backup

I'm testing neo4j enterprise 3.3.3 on AWS and trying to run an online backup on a db, which is located on a different server.

I run on my AWS instance:

```
neo4j-admin backup --backup-dir=~/backup --name=graph.db-backup --from=0.0.0.0:4444
```

where I change `0.0.0.0` for my open IP for the external neo4j db and `4444` for my port.

But then I get this error:

`Failed to load private key: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates/neo4j.key`

**UPDATE**

I fixed that by running the command with `sudo` (on Amazon AWS).

However, now I'm getting another error:

```
Failed to run a backup using the available strategies.
```

The documentation on backups says that you only need to uncomment some settings in `neo4j.conf`, which is what I've done, both on the server which is being backed up and the one that is actually running backup.

Could it be that the issue is because on AWS you have to run commands with

`systemctl`

And if so, how do I run `neo4-admin` with it?

It doesn't work if I use

`systemctl neo4j-admin ...`

Somebody from Neo4J — can you please help? Backup is one of the main reason to get the Enterprise version but there is not enough documentation on how to use it.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to find a solution for `Failed to run a backup using the available strategies.`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Basically, it looks like the best way is to first make a manual dump and to then run the neo4j admin backup script, so it updates the DB instead of writing it from scratch. Also, there are some settings you need to extend like the number of simultaneously opened files for example.